# C++ Reducing the use of pointers, raw or otherwise and/or returning nullable non-pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, raw-pointer

I am writing a Game in C++ using OpenGL and have decided to write a component based system, much alike Unity or Unreal Engine - for fun and to learn how these systems are made/work. I have reached the point where I need to implement Components and GameObjects, which I have done quite successfully.

My implementation works... it just isn't exactly how I would like it.
Currently, I store the Components as a private vector of pointers to components and return a component when it is requested.

Examples:

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(); //Returns "MeshRenderer" Component as MeshRenderer*
AddComponent(new MeshRenderer(mesh)); //Adds component to vector + returns MeshRenderer*
```

The Components are abstracts classes and are extended by components such as a MeshRenderer.

```
T *AddComponent(T *component)
{
    component->parent = this;
    m_components[typeid(T).name()] = component;

    bool pushLocation = true;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_component_locations.size(); i++)
        if (m_component_locations.at(i) == typeid(T).name())
            pushLocation = false;
    if(pushLocation)
        m_component_locations.push_back(typeid(T).name());
    return GetComponent<T>();
}
```

Above: My AddComponent(); code, used to add components - requires a pointer to a component...

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Component*> m_components; //Holds the components
std::vector<std::string> m_component_locations; //Holds data on components, allows them to be indexed
```

Above: How I store my components in the GameObject class, allows me to loop through them by index

My issues with this approach are due to how I have implemented my GetComponent() function. It returns a pointer to the Component and, potentially, a nullptr if no such Component exists.

```
T *GetComponent()
{
    if (m_components.count(typeid(T).name()) != 0)
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(m_components[typeid(T).name()]);
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

My issue here is that, due to returning a pointer, I could call delete and delete the pointer. These are raw pointers but I have made sure to ensure that they are handled by the program when the GameObject is destroyed so - hopefully (Unless I am being incompetent) no fear of memory leaks - but I'd prefer to return a reference due to the fact that you cannot call "delete" on them - to avoid any stupid mistakes that I may make.

I've made the variables private and the GameObject handles the deletion of Components and I'd prefer not to allow myself the ability to delete something due to incompetence or the like.

I have thought about returning a unique_ptr but I am unsure as to whether that implementation would be preferable.

(As an extra note, I do need the GetComponent() function to return some sort of null or give an indication that no such Component exists)

Comment: `typeid(T).name()` you shouldn't be relying on that in any way, use it only for debugging purposes as there are no guarantees about what exactly this does

Comment: Okay, do you have any suggestions on how I could alter it for the same use but without relying on `typeid(t).name()`?

Comment: You could use the hash code or `std::type_index`, see there under notes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: since you mentioned `unique_ptr`, i'll mention that there is also `shared_ptr` (in C++11); might or might not be of interest

Comment: So would this be any better?  `std::type_index(typeid(T))` It's quite late so I've only skim-read the type_index article but I'll check it out properly tommorow.

Comment: You fear to delete a pointer and want to solve that with returning a reference? Let me tell you: developers should never delete a pointer they do not possess. The reference is no cure, since getting the address of it is no big deal. Consider the following snippet to see what I mean: `int& fun(int* dyn) { return *dyn; } int main() { int* mem = new int(5); delete &(fun(mem)); }`

Comment: Possibly, but as far as I can see `shared_ptr` aren't quite what I need as I want the GameObject to have full control over the Component. If the Component is deleted, I want the GetComponent() pointer to also be deleted. What I do want to avoid is the possibility of deleting the pointer received from a GetComponent() call as this leave a gap in my GameObject's list of Components and to a couple of nasty errors.

Comment: If you want to troll anyone who tries to delete your precious objects, construct them with placement new in a memory location, where you do not place any of the objects right at the starting address - trying delete on any of those should fail.

Comment: That's actually quite a good point. I am relatively new to C++, having moved from C# and am quite wary of using pointers, especially raw pointers given that people are constantly warning against their use. (Note: I do, as far as I'm aware, understand how they work).

Comment: It's a good idea to look at `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` in this case - use them, they are generally there for this particular purpose - and they are "nullable" (or at least can be checked if they "contain anything")

Comment: Nobody should be deleting raw pointers that they have not been explicitly informed they are responsible for deleting. That being said there are ways to remind people that they don't own a pointer. You can wrap them in a non-active *smart pointer* like a `std::unique_ptr` with a *null deleter*. Also there is the Technical Specification `observer_ptr` that simply wraps the raw pointer and does nothing: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr

Comment: Incidentally you should not use *count()* in your object lookup because that means if you have one you end up searching the container twice. Faster to use *find* to begin with, then if you have one then you already have a reference to it, no need for the second lookup.

Comment: so why use pointers? making `MeshRenderer` a pointer member is non-sense. With c++11 `move` `m_components` could be a map of objects, too.

Comment: Component is an abstract class, therefor (unfortunately) I cannot create objects of it.

Comment: @Freak_ey did you ever improve on the get component method? Having problems myself finding a fool proof method to identify individual components, currently using dynamic_cast and have been informed I really shouldn't be, and typeid doesn't seem to be much better either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of reducing use of raw pointers is right. I think you have to look into [EntityX library](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx) and notice how things implemented. There are no pointers there at all.

For your case your have to do the same thing as `EntityX` does - create class `ComponentHandle` with reference (not pointer) to your component. This class does not manages life-cycle of your component. It is just an interface for your component. You can also overload `->` operator for accessing members in your component.

Good luck in C++ and component-entity-system.

Comment: EntityX's solution is exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @Freak_ey This sounds a bit like `std::reference_wrapper`, maybe you should like into it, too.